# Can I use objects created in C# within metro ui javascript code?

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I really like C# and I am familiar with it, but I also want to use HTML5/JavaScript to manage the UI for my Windows 8 Metro app. So, how can I import and use objects from a library made in C# in the Javascript files?

Example here is the starting JS code for an empty HTML5/JS project...

```
// For an introduction to the Blank template, see the following documentation:
// http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=232509
(function () {
    "use strict";

    var app = WinJS.Application;

    app.onactivated = function (eventObject) {
        if (eventObject.detail.kind === Windows.ApplicationModel.Activation.ActivationKind.launch) {
            if (eventObject.detail.previousExecutionState !== Windows.ApplicationModel.Activation.ApplicationExecutionState.terminated) {
                // TODO: This application has been newly launched. Initialize 
                // your application here.
            } else {
                // TODO: This application has been reactivated from suspension. 
                // Restore application state here.
            }
            WinJS.UI.processAll();
        }
    };

    app.oncheckpoint = function (eventObject) {
        // TODO: This application is about to be suspended. Save any state
        // that needs to persist across suspensions here. You might use the 
        // WinJS.Application.sessionState object, which is automatically
        // saved and restored across suspension. If you need to complete an
        // asynchronous operation before your application is suspended, call
        // eventObject.setPromise(). 
    };

    app.start();
})();
```

Can I pull in and use libraries and objects in JS that are written in C#?

I was kind of bummed they appear to segregate C# from HTML5 based projects...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You absolutely can do this. This is the beauty of the Windows 8 and the new application model. There are a lot of places to start and look at.

Start here: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br230301(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br230301%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) You can drill down further in the above link where it also links to a real basic sample. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh779077(v=vs.110).aspx

In a nutshell, you'll create a metro class library in C# and then set the output type of your C# from a "Class Library" to a WinMD. You can then reference and use that library in your javascript project.

There is a lot of documentation on building metro apps available at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps