# Accessing C# Variables in JavaScript

Tags: c#, javascript, windows-8

I am Developing Windows 8 application in which i have to access variables of C# class in java script function, But Unfortunately i don not know how to do this:
My C# class code is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Pakistan_Tour
{
   public class UniversalValues
{
   public static double xC;
   public static double yC;

public  static  int selectedcity;

     public int retcity() 
    {
        return selectedcity;

    }
    public void setcity(int val)
    {
         selectedcity=val;
    }
    public void setxy(double x, double y)
    {
        xC = x;
        yC = y;

    }
    public double getx()
    {
        return xC;
    }
    public double gety()
    {
        return yC;
    }


 }
}
```

I have to access the value of variables: 
    xC and yc
in java script I am doing like:

```
 function initialize() {

        var x = "<%=xC%>";

        var y = "<%=yC%>";
}
```

but is not working, Kindly help me with this, Thanks in advance.

Comment: It doesn't work like that.  You need to create a Windows Runtime Component.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh441572.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a [walkthrough](https://web.archive.org/web/20200723233729/https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/hh779077(v=vs.110)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) about calling C# from JS. Also, take a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9521047/can-i-use-objects-created-in-c-sharp-within-metro-ui-javascript-code).

Answer (score 0):

Try passing c# vaiables as parameters to your JS function

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    generateMarkersForSideBar(<%=this.LatLangStringForMap%>);
</script>
```

and in cs code

```
string _LatLangStringForMap;
public string LatLangStringForMap
{
  get { return _LatLangStringForMap; }
  set { _LatLangStringForMap = value; }
}
```